# Change body Background

Tags: javascript, html, css

I want to change background image of my body when I click a button.

**My html code lets is**

```
<body id = "body">

    <input type = "button" id = "button" value = "Change Background" onclick  = "Background_change()"></input>

</body>
```

**My CSS code is**

```
body {
    background-image : url('20a.jpg');
    font: 18px Arial ;
    color : white;
}
```

Java Script

I tried to change the image using JavaScript function using following code

```
function Background_change()
{
    var imager = document.getElementById("body").style.backgroundImage;
    imager.style.backgroundImage = url("20a.jpg");
}
```

Comment: it happens when user `click` on `button` or when `input` is `focused` ? can you explain ?

Comment: try only `var imager = document.getElementById("body")` without `.style.backgroundImage;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

1. first get the variable of body
2. then give link of image with ' or "".

```js
function Background_change(){
    var imager = document.getElementById("body");
    imager.style.backgroundImage = "url(http://im.rediff.com/money/2013/may/06car5.jpg)";
}
```

```html
<body id="body">
    <input type="button" id="button" value="Change Background" onclick="Background_change()"></input>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1):

```
document.body.style.backgroundImage = "url('yourNewImage.jpg')"
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to:

1. Reference the element, not the style property.
2. Use quotes `'` before and after the value.

Change the code like this:

```
function Background_change()
{
    var imager = document.getElementById("body");
    imager.style.backgroundImage = 'url("20a.jpg")';
}
```